# If form is submitted, then checkbox checked

Tags: php, html

I want to make it to so if my form is submitted then then the checkbox should be checked.

Here is what I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" <?php if ($_POST['submit']){ echo checked } ?> />
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    //Stuff here
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I am getting a blank page when I test it... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` and do you have an input named submit on your form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blank is because there is an php error of your php code and you have turned `error_reporting` off.

1. `if($_POST['submit'])` should be `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`
2. `echo checked` should be `echo 'checked';`

The sample below works for me.

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    //Stuff here
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo 'checked'; } ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your PHP code.Please correct it.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk" <?php if ($_POST['submit']){ echo 'checked'; } ?> />
```